# Does created_time allow you to bypass the 30 day limit on stream data?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I just want to confirm this.

The FQL documentation is somewhat vague as it states

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater

then further states

> You can use time-specific fields such as created_time along with FQL operations to retrieve a much greater range of posts

Given this statement, it would seem one could use created_time to retrieve 50 pieces of stream data at a time, regardless of date, as long as a time window was specified. However in practice it looks like I'm always limited to the past 30 days

Running this query returns 0 records:

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'owner' AND created_time < 1325376000 LIMIT 50'
```

1325376000 is the `timestamp` for '01/01/2012'. Does `created_time` not trump the 30 day time limit? I'm just looking for a definitive answer. Thanks.

Comment: I hope one of the Facebook engineers or devs can help you out on your question.  I tested briefly using the API Explorer tool and could not find any good way of getting older data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the `filter_key = 'owner'` gets used; but I was able to confirm that by using the `source_id` column, you can indeed go back and return records older than 30 days.

eg -

```
SELECT message, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time < 1325376000 LIMIT 50
```